# How to find the serial number for a Canon G1X if it has rubbed off

Tags: canon, serial-number, canon-g1-x

I recently bought a second hand Canon G1X and would like to insure it. However, the serial number  under the camera has partially rubbed off and only 6 digits are still visible. I was recommended by a local camera store to try the Chinese EOS MSG software but that did not help (incidentally, I also now can't uninstall that software from my computer).

Does anyone know how I can find out the serial number?

Comment: My 550D writes the serial number into the RAW files it creates; have you looked at those?

Comment: Only looked at JPGs so far, will check out RAW tonight. How are you viewing the serial number from the file?

Comment: In my case, Lightroom but I'm sure you can pull them out with `exiftool` or similar.

Comment: @PhilipKendall tried `exiftool` on oth jpg and raw images, no serial number :(

Comment: Chinese MSG software? That sounds delicious!

Comment: @Dan, did the SD card trick work for you ? (part 5 of my answer)

Comment: @Olivier unfortunately I have not had a chance to test that (and might not get to for a while) I would like to try it out just for completeness though and will report back as soon as I have. Thanks again for the detailed answer though!

Comment: @Dan, Ok, I'm a bit curious :)

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer :**

Use **Exiftool**, it works with JPEG and RAW and gives you the Serial Number.

**Full Answer :**

On Windows, as Philip mentioned, you can download the tool **Exiftool**, [available on its author's website](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).
The last version is currently v10.00 and is available here : http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool-10.00.zip

Unzipped the executable "exiftool(-k).exe" in the directory of your choice.

**1) The "I'm feeling lazy" way :**

Rename the executable "exiftool(-k).exe" to "exiftool(-k -serialnumber).exe" and drag and drop your file on it.
It should output something like :

```
Serial Number                   : xxxx
-- press any key --
```

**2) The "g33k" way :**

Open a console ("cmd.exe") and type :
    "path/to/exiftool(-k).exe" -serialnumber "path/to/my_image.cr2"

**3) The "I love to read" way :**

Drag and drop on top of the executable **exiftool(-k).exe** any picture taken with your Canon... and get ready for A LOT of text !

That should give you something like the following output with a **RAW** file (CR2) :

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.00
File Name                       : IMG_5936.CR2

[..bla bla bla..]

Serial Number                   : xxxx

[..bla bla bla..]

-- press any key --
```

and with a **JPEG** file :

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.00
File Name                       : IMG_5936.JPG

[..bla bla bla..]

Serial Number                   : xxx

[..bla bla bla..]

-- press any key --
```

If your aren't able to read all the information from the console window, it's because of its default settings : it doesn't keep enough information in its buffer.

To change that, go to the console properties and change the field *Screen Buffer Size**

1. Step 1 : open the console properties

[image: Step 1 : open the console properties]

2. Step 2 : change the values

[image: Step 2 : change the values]

Don't go to fast and don't stop at the *Internal Serial Number*, that's not what you are looking for. Easiest way to find it, copy/paste all the text in your favorite text editor and search for "Serial Number".

**4) The "I LOVE graphic interface" way :**

Get one more executable : **ExifToolGui**. It's available here : http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/~bogdan/

Read how to use it :)

**5) The "last chance" way :**

Still not working ? Try the following steps (tips from http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/39334705), it works for the G12 and other models :

1. Format an SD card.
2. Create an empty file on the card called "vers.req" (not "vers.req.txt" !!)
3. Put the card in the camera and start it using the rear 'playback' button, not the top on/off button.
4. Press the Func/Set button and while holding this press Disp as well (or press Func/Set and Disp buttons at the same time).

If that is not working, I'm out of idea...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with the (or my) G1X. The command line tool gives a warning "adjusted MakerData" and does not return a serial number. I tried it on other fields such as ISO and it did work for those. I also tried the drag and drop and went through the entire list, serialnumber was not there. I treid this on both raw and jpg images. If there is a setting on the camera to tell it to record the serial number onto the images it takes I could not find it.

Comment: Crap ! If ExifTool can't find it, it's probably not there. BTW, the list from http://www.stolencamerafinder.com/listmodels contains Canon g11, Canon g12 and Canon g2... but not the G1x...

Comment: Ok, new (and last) idea, using a formatted SD card...

Comment: The text output can be put into a text file for easy reading. exiftool x.jpg > x.txt